# brownie ganache chain has incorrect timestamp

Tags: yaml, ethereum, ganache

I'm playing around with an ethereum webapp. To test my frontend client, I want to perform some transactions 'in the past', so when my client reads the current timestamp, the visuals will update accordingly. For that to work, I want to start my local chain with initial block at `1980-01-01 00:00:00+00:00`.

I've edited `brownie-config.yaml` to add a `--time` option to ganache (`time: 1980-01-01T00:00:00+00:00`), and it seems to be propagated to the `ganache-cli` command, but the `chain.time` method gives me the current time:

```
$ brownie console
Brownie v1.14.6 - Python development framework for Ethereum
MyProject is the active project.
Launching 'ganache-cli --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --gasLimit 12000000 --mnemonic hill --port 8545 --time 1980-01-01 00:00:00+00:00'...
Brownie environment is ready.
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(chain.time())
datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 15, 17, 28, 37)  # Should be (1980, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
>>>
```

Am I missing something?